# Serial but not serializable?

Tags: transactions

Recently I've been having lectures about the transactions. One slide of the power point confused me for a long time. I've been understand that serializable means that two transactions could be parallel executed and result will be same as they have been executed serially right? And I've also read the definition for serial operation from Berkeley which I quote *"The easiest way to ensure isolation is to run all the operations of one transaction to completion before beginning the operations of next transaction. This is called a serial schedule"*. So base on above, I'm super confused that how could a schedule be serial but not serializable??? I mean, isn't this basically saying that I am a human but I cannot be a human??

So here is the slide
[image]

And I've confirmed with the professor multiple times that this statement is correct from his perspective.

Please help me understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the non-serializable schedule is not visualized.

Lets look at the outcome of the *interleaved schedule* as depicted above:

- (T1) a = a-100 = 100
- (T2) a = a*1.1 = **110**
- (T1) b = b+100 = 200
- (T2) b = b*1.1 = **220**

The following *serial schedule* has an identical outcome:

- (T1) a = a-100 = 100
- (T1) b = b+100 = 200
- (T2) a = a*1.1 = **110**
- (T2) b = b*1.1 = **220**

Because of this, the interleaved schedule is considered *serializable*.

However, the following interleaved schedule is non-serializable:

- (T1) a = a-100 = 100
- (T2) a = a*1.1 = **110**
- (T2) b = b*1.1 = 110
- (T1) b = b+100 = **210**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, however, the point is, how could a schedule be serial but not serializable?

Comment: Well I'm still not sure if I understand your question then cause per definition a schedule can't be both; it is either serial (transactions are executed sequentially) or interleaved (parallel). If for an interleaved schedule a serial schedule exists which preserves the outcome, then that interleaved schedule is serializable.

Comment: What might clarify things is that you ask your professor which schedule is serial and which one is (non)serializable; the slide only shows one schedule which is serializable